# Need a help in understanding corollary 8.2 in Gohberg and Goldberg.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory

The corollary is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

But I could not proof the last paragraph in it, which radius should I choose, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, as the corollary says, $\frac1{\lVert A^{-1}\rVert}$ will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corollary says that if $A \in \mathcal{O}$, (i.e. $A$ is invertible, so that  $\|A^{-1}\| > 0$), then the ball with radius $r = \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$ with centre $A$ lies inside $\mathcal{O}$ (all $B$ with $d(A,B)  =\|A-B\| < r$ are all invertible too). The exact formula is irrelevant for this question, the final paragraph just refers to the first sentence of the formulation of the corrolary, just stop reading after  "$B$ is invertible", and you're there.
The formula does help to show that $A \to A^{-1}$ is a continuous operation on $\mathcal{O}$ (which is how the book goes on).

Answer (score 1):

The $r$ is $1/\|A^{-1}\|$. That's exactly what Corollary 8.2. says.